querySelector does not work on event.target
I have onClick function but I cannot access to its children elements from the event
<div className="sortingBy" onClick={openSoring}>
<div className="checkBox" ></div>
</div>

My function:
const openFilter=(e)=>{
        e.target.querySelector('.checkBox').classList.toggle('active')
    }

These codes are in react.
After using that code I get this error
e.target.querySelector(...) is null

How can I access to children elements from event variable in onClick property?

e.target will be the element you actually clicked on - so that might be the .checkBox element here, and that doesn't have another .checkbox child within it. Use currentTarget instead.

You have reactjs as a tag,  it's unusual to update DOM nodes directly, so doing a querySelector and then classList.add is likely not the correct solution.   Also using a div as a checkbox is really thrown-ed upon for accessibility reasons.

This question is similar to: Difference between e.target and e.currentTarget. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You'll need to use currentTarget. The target self will be the deeper div that has no children.


const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const openFilter=(e)=>{
        console.log('target: ', e.target);
        console.log('currentTarget: ', e.currentTarget);
        e.currentTarget.querySelector('.checkBox').classList.toggle('active')
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <div className="sortingBy" onClick={openFilter}>
                <div className="checkBox">Click Me</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
.active {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>



